# Find any input that is not empty

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has some hidden fieldsets that are made visible when a button is clicked. If a user clicks one of the buttons to make the fieldset visible and fills out any of the fields then submits the form without filling out all the required fields or does not meet any of the validations it will return with error messages below each of the fields.

The problem I have is that when the user is returned to the form, all the fieldsets that have been opened and fully or partially filled in are back in their default state of hidden.

I want any of these fieldsets to remain open so the user can see what they have done wrong or not filled out.

I have tried the following...

```
if ($('#fieldset2').find(':input').not(':button').val() != '') {
    $('#fieldset2').css({'display':'block'});
} else {
    $('#fieldset2').css({'display':'none'});
}
```

This works but only if the first field has been filled in. I need it to look at all fields and check if any of the fields are NOT empty. (Excluding type'button').

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a real example, like a jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: Looking at this you're only deciding whether or not `#fieldset2` is being hidden, should this not refer to the elements being selected?

Comment: When you call a getter in jQuery, you only retrieve the value for the first one in the set. You have to call `each` and run the same code on each instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $.filter to filter down the item that have a value. If that count (length) is not equal to 0 then show the block.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

http://jsfiddle.net/b7uxfL4s/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#parentset2 input:not(:button)').filter(function () {
        return this.value != "";
    }).length != 0) {
        $('#fieldset2').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
    } else {
        $('#fieldset2').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter`:

```
$("input:not(:button)").filter(function () {
  return $(this).val().trim().length != 0;
});
```

I feel you are using `#fieldset2` multiple times, which is not right. `id`s should not be duplicated.

Comment: The code I provided works but only if the first field has been filled in, if the first is empty but the second is not it will not keep it open when returned. Each fieldset has its own unique id. #fieldset1, #fieldset2 etc etc

Comment: @Pezmo Do you understand, currently your question is vague without the HTML structure?

Answer (score 0):

Does this solves your problem?

$(":input").not(":empty")

Comment: My understanding of the :empty pseudo selector is that it checks elements to make sure they do not have any children and that they also do not have any inner text.